# Spark SQL join with subquery

Tags: apache-spark-sql, subquery

I need to convert the query below to a Spark SQL equivalent. Spark SQL doesn't seem to like the subquery in the join. I've tested adding it to the `WHERE` clause, but this doesn't return the expected results.

```
select XXXX
From TableA A
Join TableB B on a.Field1 = b.Field1 and a.Field2 = b.Field2 and b.Field3 = (select max(FieldX) from TableB)
Join TableC C on a.Field4 = c.Field4 and c.Field5 = (select max(FieldY from TableC)
Join TableD.. similar to above joins where subquery is used
Where a.date = XXXX and a.typeid =501
```

What's the appropriate code for running this in Spark SQL?

Comment: spark supports ansi-sql

Comment: Thanks for your edits guys.  Is anyone able to provide a solution example?